# execution of AfterDelete caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, trigger

I have tried to write a trigger on custom object Project(), which is having lookup to asset.
an asset can have many type of projects including "Collocation", what i am trying to achieve is:
to restrict project from getting created a collocation project if there is already a collocation project on same asset at any moment.
the code is working fine except in one condition i.e. if i try to delete any other type of project other than collocation type.

**here is my code**:

```
trigger restrictCollocation on MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c (after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {

  Set<Id> GroupedA = new Set<Id>();

   if(Trigger.isDelete) {
     for(MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c test:Trigger.Old) {

        GroupedA.add(test.Asset__c);   

     }   

   }
   else
   if(Trigger.isUpdate) {

     for(MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c test:Trigger.New) {

        if(test.Asset__c!=null){
        GroupedA.add(test.Asset__c);   
    }  

     }

     for(MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c test:Trigger.Old) {

        if(test.Asset__c!=null){
        GroupedA.add(test.Asset__c);   
    }   

     }   

   }
   else
   {
     for(MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c test:Trigger.New) {

        if(test.Asset__c!=null){
        GroupedA.add(test.Asset__c);   
    }   

     }
   }

   AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT COUNT(Id), Asset__c FROM MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c where recordtype.name='Collocation' AND   Asset__c IN :GroupedA GROUP BY Asset__c];

   for(AggregateResult ar:groupedResults) {

     Integer count = (INTEGER)ar.get('expr0');

     for(MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c test:Trigger.New) {
         If(count>1){
         test.addError('Second Collocation Project Under same Tenant Asset is not allowed');
         }
     }

   }

}
```

**and this is the Error**:

Validation Errors While Saving Record(s)
There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "Apex trigger Countchild caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: restrictCollocation: execution of AfterDelete caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: ()".

*i'll appreciate your help this is urgent.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the missing null guard on the first `if`; added here:

```
if (Trigger.isDelete) {
    for (MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c test:Trigger.Old) {
        if (test.Asset__c != null) GroupedA.add(test.Asset__c);   
    }   
}
```

But the error message you quote is for a `Countchild` trigger not the `restrictCollocation` trigger you have included in the question so sort that out first and update your question.

**PS**

For the delete case, inside the `AggregateResult` loop, `Trigger.new` will be null so that is a likely cause.

Also, note that the logic looks wrong in that loop to me as the message should only be set on projects that match the asset, not all the projects. Best to avoid the double nested loop too by using maps.

Comment: that was a old error message with old name, i have just updated it, and even after your suggested code, the same error is coming.

Comment: problem is i am able to delete collocation type project but not others.

Comment: @PrakharKhandelwal, Getting a line number for the NPE will help; checking "Development Mode" on your User may reveal that or turn on debug logging (see e.g. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_add_users_debug_log.htm&type=5 for how to do that).